# Current Line Indicator Frame color of Notepad++ 8.6

Tags: notepad++

Selecting 'Editing' in the Preferences window of Notepad++ 8.6 allows the user to configure how the current line should be highlighted: either highlighting the background or within a frame, the 'None' choice being irrelevant.

Besides the width of the frame, I should like to know if it is possible to change or set the outline color and how?

I'm new to Notepad++ and had a first glimpse at the user manual though I didn't find a solution. I also tried the Style Configurator. The fact is that I don't even know if it IS possible, in this release or in general.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: [Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#editing) (scroll down to *Current Line Indicator*)

> Current Line Indicator: Determines how the current line will be indicated.
>
> - ☐ None: No indicator for which line is the current line.
> - ☐ Highlight Background: Indicate the current line by highlighting the normal background color with the **Settings > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Current line background color** style’s `Background colour`.
> - ☐ Frame: Indicate the current line by drawing a rectangle frame around the text of the current line, using the color defined by **Settings > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Current line background color** style’s `Background colour`, and with the rectangle-line thickness defined by the Width slider.
>   Width: Use a slider to set the width (in pixels) for the lines of the rectangle frame for the current line.
> - (In v8.4 and earlier, this multi-control section was just listed as ☐ Enable current line highlighting in the list of checkboxes, and was the equivalent of ☐ being None and ☑ being Highlight Background.)

Notepad++ comes packaged with a default theme and a number of other themes to start with. You may customize any of those themes using the Style Configurator dialog, or by editing the underlying XML files.

Please note that the colours are essentially dependent on the chosen theme.

Try it for your needs (in case of OS Windows):

- Open Windows File Explorer
- Type `%AppData%\Notepad++\Themes` in Windows File Explorer address bar.
- In the resulting directory you'll find e.g. `Hello Kitty.xml`
- Copy this file to `Hello Kitty edited.xml`
- Close Notepad++ and restart Notepad++
- Go to Settings > Style configurator and select the new theme ``Hello Kitty edited`
- Select `Current line Background` in the `Style` list
- Click on `Background colour` and choose a colour.
- Click on<kbd>Save & Close</kbd>

**Hello Kitty default:**

[image]

**Hello Kitty edited:**

[image]